# Fullscreen issues on Android with Trigger.io (& landscape forced)

Tags: android, fullscreen, trigger.io

I'm using Trigger.io and recenlty bought a Samsung S3 (Android 4.1.1)
While testing on this device, I realized status bar was not hidden, even if fullscreen statement is in the config (and working on another phone device in 4.0.3).
I also seen this issue on a tablet android  4.0.3 (Asus Tranformer Prime)

(Landscape is also forced)

Is there anything I can do to worakound this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regression introduced by our support for the holo theme - a fix will be included in platform version v1.4.23, to be released by mid-December '12.